# TBB link with C++

Tags: c++, tbb

I am trying to do some tests with TBB at HPCG benchmark. However I didn't compiled the program successfully so far. I am getting errors like these:

```
src/ComputeSPMV_ref.o: In function `tbb::interface6::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, tbb::internal::parallel_for_body<ComputeSPMV_ref(SparseMatrix_STRUCT const&, Vector_STRUCT&, Vector_STRUCT&)::{lambda(int)#1}, int>, tbb::auto_partitioner const>::~start_for()':
ComputeSPMV_ref.cpp:(.text+0x3): undefined reference to `vtable for tbb::task'
src/ComputeSPMV_ref.o: In function `tbb::interface6::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, tbb::internal::parallel_for_body<ComputeSPMV_ref(SparseMatrix_STRUCT const&, Vector_STRUCT&, Vector_STRUCT&)::{lambda(int)#1}, int>, tbb::auto_partitioner const>::~start_for()':
ComputeSPMV_ref.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `vtable for tbb::task'
src/ComputeSPMV_ref.o: In function `tbb::interface6::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, tbb::internal::parallel_for_body<ComputeSPMV_ref(SparseMatrix_STRUCT const&, Vector_STRUCT&, Vector_STRUCT&)::{lambda(int)#1}, int>, tbb::auto_partitioner const>::execute()':
ComputeSPMV_ref.cpp:(.text+0x182): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_continuation_proxy::allocate(unsigned long) const'
ComputeSPMV_ref.cpp:(.text+0x1ad): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_child_proxy::allocate(unsigned long) const'
ComputeSPMV_ref.cpp:(.text+0x26b): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_continuation_proxy::allocate(unsigned long) const'
ComputeSPMV_ref.cpp:(.text+0x296): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_child_proxy::allocate(unsigned long) const'
ComputeSPMV_ref.cpp:(.text+0x43b): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_continuation_proxy::allocate(unsigned long) const'
ComputeSPMV_ref.cpp:(.text+0x470): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_child_proxy::allocate(unsigned long) const'
ComputeSPMV_ref.cpp:(.text+0x52c): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::is_group_execution_cancelled() const'
src/ComputeSPMV_ref.o: In function `ComputeSPMV_ref(SparseMatrix_STRUCT const&, Vector_STRUCT&, Vector_STRUCT&)':
ComputeSPMV_ref.cpp:(.text+0x9d0): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::init()'
ComputeSPMV_ref.cpp:(.text+0x9e9): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_root_with_context_proxy::allocate(unsigned long) const'
ComputeSPMV_ref.cpp:(.text+0xa29): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::get_initial_auto_partitioner_divisor()'
ComputeSPMV_ref.cpp:(.text+0xa52): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::~task_group_context()'
ComputeSPMV_ref.cpp:(.text+0xad4): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::~task_group_context()'
ComputeSPMV_ref.cpp:(.text+0xae0): undefined reference to `vtable for tbb::task'
ComputeSPMV_ref.cpp:(.text+0xaee): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_root_with_context_proxy::free(tbb::task&) const'
src/ComputeSPMV_ref.o: In function `tbb::interface6::internal::flag_task::~flag_task()':
ComputeSPMV_ref.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb10interface68internal9flag_taskD2Ev[_ZN3tbb10interface68internal9flag_taskD5Ev]+0x3): undefined reference to `vtable for tbb::task'
src/ComputeSPMV_ref.o: In function `tbb::interface6::internal::signal_task::~signal_task()':
ComputeSPMV_ref.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb10interface68internal11signal_taskD2Ev[_ZN3tbb10interface68internal11signal_taskD5Ev]+0x3): undefined reference to `vtable for tbb::task'
src/ComputeSPMV_ref.o: In function `tbb::interface6::internal::flag_task::~flag_task()':
ComputeSPMV_ref.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb10interface68internal9flag_taskD0Ev[_ZN3tbb10interface68internal9flag_taskD0Ev]+0x3): undefined reference to `vtable for tbb::task'
src/ComputeSPMV_ref.o: In function `tbb::interface6::internal::signal_task::~signal_task()':
ComputeSPMV_ref.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb10interface68internal11signal_taskD0Ev[_ZN3tbb10interface68internal11signal_taskD0Ev]+0x3): undefined reference to `vtable for tbb::task'
src/ComputeSPMV_ref.o:(.rodata+0x110): undefined reference to `typeinfo for tbb::task'
src/ComputeSPMV_ref.o:(.rodata._ZTIN3tbb10interface68internal11signal_taskE[_ZTIN3tbb10interface68internal11signal_taskE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for tbb::task'
src/ComputeSPMV_ref.o:(.rodata._ZTIN3tbb10interface68internal9flag_taskE[_ZTIN3tbb10interface68internal9flag_taskE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for tbb::task'
src/ComputeSPMV_ref.o:(.rodata._ZTVN3tbb10interface68internal9flag_taskE[_ZTVN3tbb10interface68internal9flag_taskE]+0x28): undefined reference to `tbb::task::note_affinity(unsigned short)'
src/ComputeSPMV_ref.o:(.rodata._ZTVN3tbb10interface68internal11signal_taskE[_ZTVN3tbb10interface68internal11signal_taskE]+0x28): undefined reference to `tbb::task::note_affinity(unsigned short)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/xhpcg] Error 1

Compile instruction look like this:
make
/usr/bin/g++ -DHPCG_NOMPI -DHPCG_NOOPENMP -I./src -I./src/GCC_TBB  -O3  -ltbb -std=c++11  -ffast-math -ftree-vectorize -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=0 -fopenmp   testing/main.o src/CG.o src/CG_ref.o ....
```

I downloaded and install latest source code from Intel.Also I already use -ltbb and -std=c++11 at compile time and I  include tbb files inside my code. I can't figure out the problem so far. Does anyone face anything like this before with Intel TBB? I am assuming that is something with the linking of library but I can't figure it out

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to insert "-ltbb -std=c++11" just before -o and it should work!

Answer (score 3):

Patroklos Patroklou's answer didn't help, so I put `-ltbb` at the end of my command and it **worked**.

*Ubuntu 20.04*
*g++-9, libstdc++-9-dev*